# Highlight Message in Outlook 2013 Message List

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013, highlighting

I would like to be able to right-click (or equivalent) a message in the message list and be able to highlight it in the list.  With a large collection of messages in a folder, zeroing in on the right one is not always easy, whereas a nice red (for example) band of colour in the list would be very helpful!

I don't want to auto-categorize messages to me or from a sender ... nor do I find the colour-categorization very helpful as it only colours a band in the preview pane, not in the message list.

Possible to do and I'm just missing the right option, or not possible?

Comment: My Outlook 2013 puts a coloured box on the item in the list (as well as the band on the message itself) to represent the category, doesn't your do that?  Also, why not use the follow-up flags?

Comment: I have no box when I colour-categorize, other than in the preview pane (where I get a band of colour beneath the subject).  I don't use the followup flags because I'm not following up, I just want to have a quick and "in my face" visual cue when I scroll through the list.

Answer (score 1):

You have several choices here:

1. Use the **follow up flags**.
2. Use the **color categories**.
3. Use the custom **VBA script** to set custom message property.

First two options lead to some kind of marker in the right side of message list (either flag or small colored box). Third option requires to use the **conditional formatting**. You may also want to use the conditional formatting for the options 1 and 2 to make the highlighting more clear.

To color your message list, open the **VIEW** tab on the ribbon and click the **View Settings** button (on Current View group). Now click the **Conditional Formatting...** button. **Add** new rule and click the **Font...** button to customize font color/style, click OK and then click the **Condition...** button.

Now you can specify (on **More Choices** tab) either **Categories** or **Only items which** are flagged. You can also specify your custom properties on the **Advanced** tab if you're using the 3rd option.